How to change sidenote's fontsize in kaobook
How could I change the \sidenote's fontsize in kaobook? Is there a parameter for it on \documentclass or something?
More specifically, I want to be able to modify kaobook's \sidenote command, either individually or (better) generally to modify fontsize. I am able to do this in the documentclass:
\documentclass[
    a4paper, % Page size
    **fontsize**=10.5pt, % Base font size
    twoside=true,...]{kaobook}

But this modifies both normal text and sidenotes. I'd like to modify just sidenotes.

Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal document demonstrating what you want to change? What is kaobook? I can't find a class or package by that name in TeX Live.

Thanks for the answer! kaobook is a LaTeX class for books. Sorry if this is not the proper forum. I found other answers to kaobook questions so I thought it might be.
About the minimal document, I want to be able to modify kaobook's \sidenote command, either individually or (better) generally to modify fontsize.
I am able to do this in the documentclass:
\documentclass[
a4paper, % Page size
fontsize=10.5pt, % Base font size
twoside=true,...]{kaobook}
But this modifies both normal text and sidenotes. I'd like to modify just sidenotes.

I've flagged your comment for somebody to take a look as I'm not sure why you can't edit.

Does this answer your question? How to modify fonts in sidenotes?
